# Changing UITableViewController to UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview, superclass

I'm trying to use the superclass ATSDragToReorderTableViewController but the problem I have is that I'm using a UIViewController with a table view instead of a UITableViewController. I've tried changing the superclass to a UIViewController but that brings up a load of errors, the main one being 'property tableView not found on object of type ATSDragToReorderTableViewController*'

Has anyone come across a similar problem?

Comment: You'll probably have an easier time making your view controller a `UITableViewController`.

Comment: The problem I have with that is there are other things besides a table I want to put on the view.

Comment: did you set the delegate and data source?

Comment: Yeah both delegate and data source are set. The only other error I'm getting, apart from the one mentioned above, is 'No visible @interface for UIViewController declares the selector 'initWithStyle'.

Answer (score 2):

Change the superClass of `ATSDragToReorderTableViewController` from `UITableViewController` to `UIViewController`. Add `< UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate >`, and then add property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

Comment: This still crashed my application. Whenever i change the type of self from UIViewController to UITableViewController, my application crahses...

Comment: I never did get this to work. Ended up leaving out of my app.

Comment: By default, ATSDragToReorderTableViewController is subclassed from UITableViewController, this mean that it have by default property tableView.  If you change a class from UITableViewController to UIViewController, you must have a property tableview in your class. If you are using xib, you must connect
 this elements! It worked for me in a xib with a tableview very nice...